# Custom Event Triggers in Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, events, expression-blend, eventtrigger

Hi I have been learning WPF with "Expression Blend 4" last few days and this is what I want to accomplish.

I have a Main Window which has a single custom button in it.

What I want to do is that when the Mouse Cursor is to the left side of the Window, I want the button to start its animation and move to my cursor. Alternatively, when the cursor is at the right side of the window, I want the button to move right.

I have created custom events for this. I already tested them with "MessageBox"s to pop up if I either move left or right. In actual fact I want them to animate left or right. But in order to create an animation timeline, I cant find my custom events on blend. Is there a way to go about this?

Partial Code Below

```
private event EventHandler MoveRightEvent;
private event EventHandler MoveLeftEvent;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    MoveRightEvent += new EventHandler(MainWindow_MoveRightEvent);
    MoveLeftEvent += new EventHandler(MainWindow_MoveLeftEvent);
    }

void MainWindow_MoveLeftEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Moved Left!!");
}

void MainWindow_MoveRightEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Moved Right!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question was about [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724009%28v=expression.40%29) (please note that in this case you must use [RoutedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) and not .NET Event) but your question is begging for custom Behavior as in this example: [WPF Tutorial: Behaviors](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html)